# generate a url in different cases of object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I just want to know how can I check and generate a url in differen cases

I've got 3 cases (3 types of object):

```
"repositories": {
  "toto": {
    "tata": "https://google.com/",
    "titi": "images"  
 }
},
```

the second case:

```
"repositories": {
"toto": {
  "tata": "https://google.com/",
  "titi": ""  // string empty
 }
},
```

the third case:

```
"repositories": {
"toto": {
  "tata": "https://google.com/",
   // no titi key
 }
},
```

What I need to do it's to generate a url taking into account this 3 different cases

I don't understand how can I do the 2 and 3 case in same script

In my script I'm doing

```
else if (type === "toto") {
        const totoURi = repositories.toto.tata;
        const titi = repositories.toto.titi; 
        // I don't understand how can I do the 2 and 3 case in same script

        const url =
            totoURi +
            titi +
            "." +
            type;
       // example of first case : https://google.com/images.toto
       // expected 2nd case : https://google.com.toto
       // expected 3rd case : https://google.com.toto
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: I do some modifications sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this - using the [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

```js
const makeUrl = rep => {
  const url = new URL(rep.toto.tata);
  url.pathname = rep.toto.titi ?? "";
  return url;
}

const repositories1 = { "toto": { "tata": "https://google.com/", "titi":  "images" } }
const repositories2 =  {"toto": {"tata": "https://google.com/", "titi": ""  /* string empty */ }}
const repositories3 =  { "toto": { "tata": "https://google.com/", /* no titi key */ } }

console.log(makeUrl(repositories1))
console.log(makeUrl(repositories2))
console.log(makeUrl(repositories3))
```

For older browsers

```js
const makeUrl = rep => {
  const url = new URL(rep.toto.tata);
  url.pathname = rep.toto.titi ? rep.toto.titi : "";
  return url;
}

const repositories1 = { "toto": { "tata": "https://google.com/", "titi":  "images" } }
const repositories2 =  {"toto": {"tata": "https://google.com/", "titi": ""  /* string empty */ }}
const repositories3 =  { "toto": { "tata": "https://google.com/", /* no titi key */ } }

console.log(makeUrl(repositories1))
console.log(makeUrl(repositories2))
console.log(makeUrl(repositories3))
```

Comment: can you explain me the 3rd line (url.pathname = rep.toto.titi ?? "";)

Comment: Alternative: `url.pathname = rep.toto.titi ? rep.toto.titi : "";`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const object0 = {
    repositories: {
      toto: {
        tata: "https://tata/",
        titi: "titi"
      }
    }
  },
  object1 = {
    repositories: {
      toto: {
        tata: "https://tata/",
        titi: ""
      }
    }
  },
  object2 = {
    repositories: {
      toto: {
        tata: "https://tata/"
      }
    }
  };

function genUrl(object) {
  const keys = object.repositories.toto;
  let url = "";
  Object.values(keys).forEach((val) => (url = url + val));
  return url;
}

console.log(genUrl(object0));
console.log(genUrl(object1));
console.log(genUrl(object2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just include a nullish check

```js
const obj1 =  {
  "tata": "https://google.com/",
  "titi": "images"
};

const obj2 =  {
  "tata": "https://google.com/",
  "titi": ""
};

const obj3 =  {
  "tata": "https://google.com/",
};

function checkCase(obj) {
  if (obj.titi === null || obj.titi === undefined) return "case 3"
  if (!obj.titi) return "case 2"
  return "case 1"
}

console.log(checkCase(obj1));
console.log(checkCase(obj2));
console.log(checkCase(obj3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `.toto`, you described in your question, this yields the result:

```js
const case1 = {
  "repositories": {
    "toto": {
      "tata": "https://google.com",
      "titi": "images"
    }
  }
};

const case2 = {
  "repositories": {
    "toto": {
      "tata": "https://google.com",
      "titi": "" // string empty
    }
  }
};

const case3 = {
  "repositories": {
    "toto": {
      "tata": "https://google.com",
      // no titi key
    }
  }
};

const makeUrl = caseNum => {
  const url = new URL(caseNum.repositories.toto.tata)
  url.pathname = caseNum.repositories.toto.titi ? caseNum.repositories.toto.titi : "";
  let urlString = url.toString();
  if (urlString.charAt(urlString.length - 1) == '/') {
    urlString = urlString.slice(0, -1);
  }
  return `${urlString}.toto`;
}

console.log(makeUrl(case1));
console.log(makeUrl(case2));
console.log(makeUrl(case3));
```